# Dynamically adding components with ngFor doesn't work when updating the list of items I want to display

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to have a component in angular dynamically add components to one of its container. I achieved this perfectly fine with `ngFor` and without a `DynamicComponentLoader`. This worked fine if I gave a list of the items I wanted to display prior to the construction of the object. Now, I initially have an empty list that will have items added, removed and updated. I want the components made from that list to reflect changes made from that list.

Here is my current code:

HTML:

```
<div id = "simple_pov_games_container">
        <app-games-card-view *ngFor = "let gameCard of simplePOVGames; let i = index"
          [gameCard] = "gameCard">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </app-games-card-view>
</div>
```

component

```
  public simplePOVgames: ICommonGameCard[] = [];
  private addGameCard(gamecard: ICommonGameCard): void {
    gamecard.pov === POVType.Simple
    ? this.simplePOVgames.push(gamecard)
    : this.freePOVgames.push(gamecard);
  }
```

Unfortunately, the components are not being added to the HTML when I add elements to the list. Is there any other way to do this than having to use a `DynamicComponentLoader`?

Comment: Maybe an async `Observable`?

Comment: Your code seems it would work What does the `console.log` output for `gamecard` parameter of `addGameCard` method?